# Embeded Form Collection doesn't remove item Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem. I'm working on a Symfony 2 based web app and I embedding a from collection to another one based on the Symfony Cookbook entry (This: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_collections.html ).
Recently I changed my bundle's mapping data to annotation from yaml. 
The problem starts here. Persisting new elements works fine, but I can't remove anything.

I have a Page entity and an Image entity and they have a many to many relation. I embed and image upload form collection to the Page's form.

The old mapping was invalid, the new one is valid but doesn't work.

Here are my old and new mappings:

old yml:

page:

```
manyToMany:
        images:
            targetEntity: Image
            inversedBy: page
            cascade: [persist, remove]
            orderBy:
                image_order: DESC
```

no mapping on the image

New mapping:

Page:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="pages", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="page_image",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"image_order" = "DESC"})
    */
    protected $images;
```

Image:

```
/**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="images")
      */
    protected $pages;
```

The action that handles the edit form submission:

```
/**
     * Edits an existing Page entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/update", name="page_update")
     * @Method("post")
     * @Template("AdamantiumBackendBundle:Page:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('AdamantiumBackendBundle:Page')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Page entity.');
        }

        $editForm   = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) { 

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();                   
            apc_clear_cache('user');            
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('AdamantiumBackendBundle:Page:edit.html.twig',array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

The embeded collection from the Page form:

```
->add('images', 'collection', array('type' => new ImageType(),
                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                            'allow_delete' => true,
                                            'by_reference' => false,
                                            'options' => array('data_class' => 'Adamantium\BackendBundle\Entity\Image'),
                                        ))
```

I have the add and remove Images methods, I have getters and setters. (and as I said earlier everything worked fine with the invalid yml mapping)

So please tell me what am I missing or what do I do wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you try to remove them? Also, did you set `'allow_delete' => true` in the form builder?

Comment: Yes I have the 'allow_delete' => true. I use the same method as they described in the documentation.

Comment: Just to make sure: In the docs they remove tags by removing them from the DOM in the edit form. Is that how you do it too? because in your case I see you have a delete_form..

Comment: Yes. I do it that way. delete_form is for another purpose